# Ride Doesn't open in Python 3.7 - WXPython problem

Tags: wxpython, robotframework, robotframework-ide

After installing Robot Framework, WxPython and Ride , when I am trying to open the Ride IDE, I get the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\application\application.py", line 59, in
> OnInit
>     self._plugin_loader.enable_plugins()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\application\pluginloader.py", line 43, in
> enable_plugins
>     p.enable_on_startup()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\application\pluginconnector.py", line 52,
> in enable_on_startup
>     self.enable()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\application\pluginconnector.py", line 57,
> in enable
>     self._plugin.enable()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunnerplugin.py",
> line 162, in enable
>     self._build_ui()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunnerplugin.py",
> line 558, in _build_ui
>     self._build_notebook_tab()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunnerplugin.py",
> line 734, in _build_notebook_tab
>     self.out = self._create_output_textctrl()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunnerplugin.py",
> line 769, in _create_output_textctrl
>     font = self._create_font()   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunnerplugin.py",
> line 789, in _create_font
>     font=wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_ANSI_FIXED_FONT) wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion
> "wxFontEnumerator::IsValidFacename(font.GetFaceName())" failed at
> ..\..\src\msw\settings.cpp(301) in wxSystemSettingsNative::GetFont():
> OnInit returned false, exiting... Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
> wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this"
> failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(478) in
> wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have
> been removed
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Which version of wxPython and RIDE are you using?

Comment: Hi, Ride: 1.7.3.1 and WxPython 4.0.4 . Python 3.7.2 and Windows 10

Comment: According to their documentation, it should work. There is a slightly newer version available that you could try though: https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.4.rst

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problem is related with the font selection on wxPython. You can try to update wxPython for the newest version, 4.0.6:

```
pip install -U wxPython
```

You can also upgrade RIDE, with:

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-ride==1.7.4b1
```

(Note: See the https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/F.A.Q.)